# I am getting "Could not retrieve transport type data for Receive Location 'Receive Location2' from config store"

Tags: biztalk, single-sign-on

Could not retrieve transport type data for Receive Location 'Receive Location2' from config store. Both SSO Servers (Primary='' and Backup='') failed. Backup server failure: Cannot perform encryption or decryption because the secret is not available from the master secret server. See the event log (on computer '******') for related errors.
(Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)

Whatever I try to do, even start the orchestration, I am getting above message.
I tried to restore secret database from backup file but I am getting message 'bad data'.
Please help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is SSO running?  Did you change the password to the account SSO runs under?  Did you install VS 2010?  Also, what version of BizTalk?

If you installed VS2010:
http://tomas-simonavicius.blogspot.com/2010/02/sso-service-failed-to-start-after.html

If you changed the password to the account SSO runs under you need to restore the master secret:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560589%28v=bts.20%29.aspx

Comment: I am also getting the same error. I have changed the SSO service account and starts to get this error.Please tell me how to fix this error. I dont have the backup of Secret .

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I did successfully restore the SSCO but my service was running fine anyway

Answer (score 2):

After a long time of googling finally I got the problem resolved. The steps I followed are as follows:

Go To SSO Adminnistration -> System -> Restore Secret and select the secret file.

If you dont know the path of the secret file try once in the location "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On".

Select the file and provide the password. Once the master secret restores the error will not come.

Comment: Tried that, service was running fine to begin with but still cannot delete App or port.